# Seekbar OR Horizontal LinearLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, seekbar

I need to do something like this image in my android APP, and I don't know which is the best way to do it.

Values will be between 0 and 150, and numbers have to scroll horizontally of course (the mask is static).

I have the mask image with the lines, and I think I should put the numbers in an horizontal LinearLayout full of TextViews programmatically. I know the exact margin the TextViews should have (in dp).

After scrolling, TextViews must stop at the larger lines, and I have to be able to get the number of the center (current selected value).

How would you achieve this?

[image: "seekbar"]

**SOLUTION:**

Using [HorizontalPicker library](https://github.com/blazsolar/HorizontalPicker) it has been easy to achieve what I want.

The layout will look like this.

```
<RelativeLayout    
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">


<com.wefika.horizontalpicker.HorizontalPicker
    android:id="@+id/picker"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="@integer/picker_text_size"
    app:sideItems="3"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="-1"
    />
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/mask_image"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
```

Comment: https://github.com/rtugeek/ColorSeekBar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check [this](https://github.com/blazsolar/HorizontalPicker) it may fulfill your requirment.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this code before (sorry it's not open source or anything), so I have some bad news for you. It's a bit more complicated than that.

Most of what you're asking could theoretically be accomplished with a RecyclerView, something similar to the code below:

```
RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler);
rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, HORIZONTAL, false);
rv.setAdapter( // Some adapter that will generate the TextViews with numbers and the lines above/below the numbers);
```

then the static overlay, you just add in a separate layout.

That problem with the code above is that you will not be able to do this part:

> After scrolling, TextViews must stop at the larger lines

The only way I found to accomplish this, is by creating a 100% custom view. That means, you'll have to start with the following code:

```
public class CustomHorizontalSeekBar extends View {
```

This class will have touch events and a contain a [Scroller](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Scroller.html) to aid in the scrolling, acceleration, deceleration and will have to directly override

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
}
```

to execute all the drawing directly on the canvas, it's quite a bit work to accomplish perfect, but it's for sure a satisfactory end result.

Best of luck n happy coding.

Comment: Not too difficult with the library I have used. Check the solution in my edited question.